# Ansible: What would be the preferred way of running several tasks on different groups?

Tags: ansible

Let's say we have 3 services and 5 servers and
Service 1 should run on all servers.
Service 2 should run on server 1, 2 and 3.
Service 3 should run on server 4 and 5.

I could think of a few dirty ways to accomplish that, but I'd like to know what the best-practice for that scenario would be.

I was thinking that it might be a good idea to first define a group for each service that specifies the hosts that it should be deployed on in the inventory file:

```
[service-1]
server-[01:05]

[service-2]
server-[01:03]

[service-3]
server-[04:05]
```

To get the services on the target machines I would use [copy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html) or [template](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html).
And for actually starting services I found [this](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/service_module.html).

But how would I make the services start on only those machines that they are supposed to run on?

I guess I could create multiple playbooks to achieve that, but I would really prefer to put everything into one playbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A playbook can have multiple plays. Therefore you indeed can use those groups to archive your goal and still only have one playbook:

```
- name: Setup service 1
  hosts: service-1
  tasks/roles: ...

- name: Setup service 2
  hosts: service-2
  tasks/roles: ...

- name: Setup service 3
  hosts: service-3
  tasks/roles: ...
```

Alternatively you can filter you roles/tasks with conditions like so:

```
- name: Setup all service
  hosts: all
  roles:
    - role: service1
      when: "'service-1' in group_names"

    - role: service2
      when: "'service-2' in group_names"

    - role: service3
      when: "'service-3' in group_names"
```

`group_names` is a magic variable and holds all the groups the current host belongs to.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. :)